# Observer not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, wifi, observers

I am trying to make an observer to notify me whenever my laptop it automatically changes its wifi connection.

I have a "NetworkProperties" class where I store my connection properties:

```
@interface NetworkProperties : NSObject
{
@public
    CWInterface *wfi;
@private
    CWWiFiClient *wfc;

    NSString *SSID;
    NSString *BSSID;
    NSString *phyMode;
    NSString *hwAddr;
    NSString *securityType;
}
@end
```

and a "GUIHandle" class where I try to handle my GUI. I also have the following functions to enable/disable the scaning:

```
@interface GUIHandle : NSObject
{
    NetworkProperties *NP;
}

-(IBAction)startScan:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)stopScan:(id)sender;

@end

-(IBAction)startScan:(id)sender
{
    done = 0;

    NP = [[NetworkProperties alloc] init];
    [NP scanNetworkProperties];

    [NP->wfi addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bssid" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew  context:nil];
}

-(IBAction)stopScan:(id)sender
{
    [NP->wfi removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bssid"];
}


- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    NSLog(@"We are here!\n");
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"bssid"]) {
        NSLog(@"Value changed!\n");
    }
}
```

However I do not get any notification if the "bssid" of my connection is changing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide .m file for networkproperties class?

Comment: Sure : https://paste.ofcode.org/FUTYGZg3qQPDF2JGgkUXqx

Comment: Is `bssid` observable?

Comment: I managed the problem using this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corewlan/cweventdelegate . Thank you!